# Change Superfish menu on specific pages

Tags: 8, navigation

Is there any way I can change the menu in Superfish module in specific pages? What I know so far is that Superfish uses the "Main Navigation" in the admin structures by default. Can I create a customised menu and make Superfish use that menu?

Comment: This looks like a support request to the Superfish third-party module on drupal.org. You should open an issue in its issue queue on drupal.org then, not here.

Comment: How did you place the Superfish menu initially? As a block? Then you simply can use the block visibility settings to hide the menu on certain pages. And have another menu block's visibility settings configured to appear only on these certain pages. If your CSS is robust enough, the same styles will apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want Mega menu(Navigation),As your requirement you need to create custom menu module.

Using these module - https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras. You can make your own fields,which are u need to print making new block from custom module.

Hope my suggestion will help u.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems OP simply wants to load another menu structure on certain pages.

Comment: Yes need to load another menu,according to requirement

Comment: I didn't know about this module, thanks so much prashant!